# Recognizability of PFTM

Tags: formal-languages, computability, turing-recognizable

I encountered this problem here: [https://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs172/ps05.pdf](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Etrevisan/cs172/ps05.pdf)

Consider the language
$$PFTM := \{\langle M \rangle : \text{$M$ is a Turing machine and $L(M)$ is prefix free} \}$$

where L(M) is the set of strings accepted by M.

(a) Prove that PFTM is undecidable.
(b) Is PFTM recognizable?
(c) Is the complement of PFTM recognizable?

I think I have a proof for a, but I'm unsure about how to go about b and c. I tried a mapping reduction from $A_{TM}$ to both but couldn't really figure it out.